# Is there a function similar to ncdisp to view .npy files?

Tags: python, numpy, file-type

Is there a function similar to `ncdisp` in MATLAB to view .npy files?

Alternatively, it would be helpful to have some command that would spit out header titles in a .npy file. I can see everything in the file, but it is absolutely enormous. There has to be a way to view what categories of data are in this file.

Comment: most of us dont know matlab... so your question doesnt mean anything to us...

Comment: thank you for the helpful response. Alternatively, it would be helpful to have some command that would spit out header titles in a .npy file. I can see everything in the file, but it is absolutely enormous. There has to be a way to view what categories of data are in this file.

Comment: A `npy` has only one array, with one `dtype`. If it is object dtype, the header doesn't tell us anything about the elements.  It might help if you told us more about the file(s) in question.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the code for `np.lib.npyio.load` we see that it calls `np.lib.format.read_array`.  That in turn calls as `np.lib.format._read_array_header`.

This can studied and perhaps even used, but it isn't in the public API.

But if you are such a MATLAB fan as you claim, you already know (?) that you can explore `.m` files to see the MATLAB code.  Same with `python/numpy`.  Read the files/functions until you hit compiled 'builtin' functions.

Since a `npy` contains only one array,the header isn't that interesting by itself - just the array dtype and shape (and total size).  This isn't like the matlab save file with lots of variables. `scipy.io.loadmat` can read those.

But looking up `ncdisp` I see that's part of its `NetCDF` reader.  That's a whole different kind of file.